# How to utilize the SBCL provided semaphore against race conditions

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

As far as my knowledge about semaphores goes, a semaphore is used to protect resources which can be counted and are vulnerable to race conditions. But while reading the SBCL documentation of semaphores I could not figure out, how to properly use the provided semaphore implementation to protect a resource.

A usual work flow, as I recall would be:

1. a process wants to retrieve some of the by the semaphore protected
   data (which is for the sake of the example a trivial queue). As the
   semaphore counter is 0, the process waits
2. another process puts something in the queue and as the semaphore is
   incremented, a signal is sent to all waiting processes

Given the possibility of interleaving, one has to protect any of those resource accesses as they might not be in that order, or any linear order at all. Therefore e.g. Java interprets each class as an implicit monitor and provides a `syncronized` keyword with which a programmer can define a protected area which can only be accessed by one process at a time.

How to I emulate this functionality in common-lisp, as I am pretty sure my current code is as thread safe as without the semaphore, as the semaphore has no clue what code to protect.

```
;;the package 
(defpackage :tests (:use :cl :sb-thread)) 
(in-package :tests)

(defclass thread-queue ()
  ((semaphore
    :initform (make-semaphore :name "thread-queue-semaphore"))
   (in-stack
    :initform nil)
   (out-stack
    :initform nil)))


(defgeneric enqueue-* (queue element)
  (:documentation "adds an element to the queue"))

(defgeneric dequeue-* (queue &key timeout)
  (:documentation "removes and returns the first element to get out"))

(defmethod enqueue-* ((queue thread-queue) element)
  (signal-semaphore (slot-value queue 'semaphore))
  (setf (slot-value queue 'in-stack) (push element (slot-value queue 'in-stack))))


(defmethod dequeue-* ((queue thread-queue) &key timeout)
  (wait-on-semaphore (slot-value queue 'semaphore) :timeout timeout)
  (when (= (length (slot-value queue 'out-stack)) 0)
    (setf (slot-value queue 'out-stack) (reverse (slot-value queue 'in-stack)))
    (setf (slot-value queue 'in-stack) nil))
  (let ((first (car (slot-value queue 'out-stack))))
    (setf (slot-value queue 'out-stack) (cdr (slot-value queue 'out-stack)))
    first))


(defparameter *test* (make-instance 'thread-queue))

(dequeue-* *test* :timeout 5)

(enqueue-* *test* 42)

(enqueue-* *test* 41)

(enqueue-* *test* 40)

(dequeue-* *test* :timeout 5)

(dequeue-* *test* :timeout 5)

(dequeue-* *test* :timeout 5)

(dequeue-* *test* :timeout 5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you already have is a semaphore of count = 0, on which consumers wait.

What you also need is an exclusive lock around access your stacks (perhaps one for each), or alternatively a lock-free queue. If you want/must use semaphores, a binary semaphore can serve as an exclusive lock.

---

EDIT:
In SBCL, you already have [lock-free queues](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Section-sb_002dconcurrency_003aqueue), you might want to use one of these instead of two stacks. Another possibility is to use [atomic operations](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Atomic-Operations).

Finally, if that still doesn't suit you, use a [mutex](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Mutex-Support), wrapping code that acesses and updates the stacks inside `with-mutex` or `with-recursive-lock`.

Be sure to use the lock/mutex **after** waking up from the semaphore, not **around** the waiting for the semaphore, otherwise you lose the advantage that semaphores give you, which is the possibility of waking up multiple waiters in a row, instead of one at a time.

You can read all about these things in the [SBCL manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/index.html).

Also, I think some work has been done to rename every lock-like thing in SBCL to `lock`, according to [this blog post](http://random-state.net/log/3523852985.html), but I don't know the status of it and it states that the old names will be supported for a while.

---

You'll almost surely also need a semaphore of count = limit for producers, to not exceed your queue limit.

In your `enqueue-*`, you should signal the semaphore **after** updating the queue. The `setf` is not needed, `push` already stores the new head of the list in place.

In your `dequeue-*`, `length` is a lengthy function when applied to lists, but checking if a list is empty is cheap with `null` or `endp`. Instead of taking the `car` and store the `cdr`, you can use `pop`, it does exactly that.

Comment: well using locks additionally to the semaphore would open up two possibilities:
(a)use the semaphore inside the lock -> very dangerous as this may result in a deadlock if the process waits for the semaphore but does not return the outer lock
(b)use the semaphore outside the lock -> well, then I gained nothing but a fancy counter I could have implemented myself.
I hoped the given implementation would provide a neat way of securing code. If there is no such possibility. Please edit in my remark (a) and I will accept it as an answer.
(Your are right about the other stuff though)

Comment: @Sim, ok, I'll add your remark to my answer. Also, note that you gain something with semaphores: passive waiting and wake up multiple waiters in a row.

Comment: @Sim, I added a couple of words to the initial paragraphs to make them more clear. The previous version could give the impression that using a lock for exclusive resource access was a replacement for semaphores.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hold a mutual exclusion semaphore (aka a 'mutex') for the duration of your queue operations.  Use a SBCL mutex as such:

```
(defclass thread-queue ()
  ((lock :initform (sb-thread:make-mutex :name 'thread-queue-lock))
   ...))

(defmethod enqueue-* ((queue thread-queue) element)
  (sb-thread:with-recursive-lock ((slot-value queue 'lock))
    (setf (slot-value queue 'in-stack) (push element (slot-value queue 'in-stack)))))

* (defvar lock (sb-thread:make-mutex))
LOCK

* lock
#S(SB-THREAD:MUTEX
   :NAME NIL
   :%OWNER NIL
   :LUTEX #<unknown pointer object, widetag=#x5E {11CEB15F}>)

* (sb-thread:with-recursive-lock (lock) 'foo)    
FOO

* (sb-thread:with-recursive-lock (lock) (sb-thread:with-recursive-lock (lock) 'foo))
FOO
```

Presumably the `with-recursive-lock` macro will do the right thing (unlock the lock, using `unwind-protect` or some such) for a non-local exit.

This is the equivalent of Java `synchronized` - the above protects the `enqueue-*` method; you'd need to do it to every other method that can be called asynchronously.